# How to create new observable from the result of another observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have a function that returns an Observable as result of a http request. I want to create a store in the memory for these functions but when I call one I want to emit the new result of this for the original context of that function.

In my case I have a theme service that has a store, a relaod contents function and register new loader function.

Theme service class

```
....
contentLoaderRegistry = [];

  public reloadRegistratedContents(){
    this.contentLoaderRegistry.forEach((loader) => {
      loader();
    });
  }

  public registerThemeDependentContentLoader(loader:()=>Observable<SafeHtml>):Observable<SafeHtml>{
    const loaderWrapper:() => Observable<SafeHtml> = ():Observable<SafeHtml> => {
      return Observable.create((observer) => {
        try{
          observer.next(  ...???   loader());
        }catch(err){
          observer.error(err);
        }
        return () => {
          //observer.complete();
        };
      });
    };
    this.contentLoaderRegistry.push(loaderWrapper);
    return loaderWrapper();
  }
....
```

The loader parameter is implementing the http call of an svg image. When theme is changed reloadRegistratedContents function will be called and here the view should be patched with the new svg contents.

I also have a pipe that should do the magic:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'themeDependentContent'
})
export class ThemeDependentContentPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(
    private _theme:ThemeService,
    private _http:HttpClient,
    private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer
  ){}

  transform(url:string):Observable<SafeHtml> {
    let themeDependentContentLoader:()=>Observable<SafeHtml> = () => {
      return this._http.get(url, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml'), responseType: 'text'}).pipe(map<string, SafeStyle>((svg:string) => {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(svg);
      }));
    }
    return this._theme.registerThemeDependentContentLoader(themeDependentContentLoader);
  }

}
```

If the result of registerThemeDependentContentLoader function could emit(next) the svg at the beginning and every time when reloadRegistratedContents is called it would be nice. On the other hand this code returns something like: `Observable<Observable<SafeHtml>>` insted of `Observable<SafeHtml>`. SO probably I should wrap the result of loader parameter function's observable but I dont know how to.

Could someone who have more experience help me out in this?
Thank you for your time and answers.

#### Edit 1

I could make it work with Subject but I guess it is not the best practice here:

```
public registerThemeDependentContentLoader(loader:()=>Observable<SafeHtml>):Observable<SafeHtml>{
    
    let observer = new Subject<SafeHtml>();
    const loaderWrapper = () => {
      loader().subscribe((svg) => {
        observer.next(svg);
      }, (err) => {
        observer.error(err);
      });
    }

    this.contentLoaderRegistry.push(loaderWrapper);
    return observer;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your use case enough to provide the exact code you need, but to generally answer the question of how to create a new Observable from the result of another Observable, I use code like this:

```
  selectedProductSuppliers$ = this.selectedProduct$
    .pipe(
      switchMap(selectedProduct =>
        forkJoin(selectedProduct.supplierIds.map(supplierId => this.http.get<Supplier>(`${this.suppliersUrl}/${supplierId}`)))
      )
    );
```

Each time a new product is selected, the product is emitted into the `this.selectedProduct$` stream.

This uses `forkJoin` to create a new Observable from that selected product's list of suppliers, get each one via `http.get` and join the result.

In general, whenever you need to create an Observable within another Observable, you want to use a higher-order mapping operator (such as switchMap, mergeMap, or concatMap). The higher-order mapping operators handle the subscriptions to the inner Observables.

Comment: Sorry if I could not make it clear. This case is not about trigger multiple http request to individual endpoints and join them. I have an event when user or OS (dark mode light mode) changes the theme of the application. At that moment I need to reload every registered svg, because their content also changes because of a service worker (mainly their color). So I want to http get once at the beginning and every time when the request's wrapper function is called so I can use the async pipe in my template to refresh the svg content at every theme changed event.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass in observer in your loader().subscribe for it to work

```
 try{
       loader().subscribe(observer)          
    }catch(err){
      observer.error(err);
    }
```

Comment: In this case I get the result of the first http get but when reloadRegistratedContents function is called the observer does not next the result again.

Comment: haven't seen any subscribe calls in your code, so don't know where it actually executes.

Comment: It executes in the template via integrated async pipe

Comment: reloadRegistratedContents doesn't return an observable, how it works with async pipe

Comment: When 'loader()' is called in reloadRegistratedContents observer of registerThemeDependentContentLoader next the svg contnet so ThemeDependentContentPipe returns it into template and I call async pipe on that result.